# Problem with recursivity in rebol

Tags: rebol

I have a block on which I want to iterate recursively

```
folders: [
    Chrome [
        content [
            preferences
            prefpages
        ]
    ]
    icons [
        default
    ]
    locale [
        en-EN [
            csbar
        ]
    ]
    skin
]
```

with this function:

```
iterate-folder: func [folders [block!]][
    foreach folder folders [
        either not block? folder [
            probe folder
            temp: folder
            input
        ] [
            print "folder"
            probe folder
            print "folders"
            probe folders
            probe select folders folder
            type-folder: type? select folders folder
            probe type-folder
            input
            iterate-folder select folders folder
        ]
    ]
]
```

but for stupid reason I can't see, probe folder returns none above so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's that **select folders folder** that is messsing it up, I think.....**folder** is already the data structure you want.

Try this (note also the **ask** rather than **input** just to add a debugging string at that point):

```
iterate-folder: func [folders [block!]][
    foreach folder folders [
        either not block? folder [
            probe folder
            temp: folder
            ask "continue/not block"
    ] [
            print "folder"
            probe folder
            print "folders"
            probe folders
            probe select folders folder
            type-folder: folder
            probe type-folder
            ask "continue/block"
            iterate-folder folder 
        ]
    ]
]
```